# Discard file extensions in compressing all from directory using SharpCompress

Tags: c#, compression

I am using http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/ to compress a directory:

```
using (var archive = ZipArchive.Create())
{
    archive.AddAllFromDirectory(folderPath);
}
```

Would it be possible to discard files with a special extension: .dll in a selected folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the files individually and filter out the ones you don't want.

```
using (var zip = File.OpenWrite("C:\\test.zip"))
  using (var zipWriter = WriterFactory.Open(ArchiveType.Zip, zip))
  {

  FileInfo[] fi = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
  foreach(var f in fi)
  {
    if(f.Extension != ".dll")
      zipWriter.Write(Path.GetFileName(file), filePath);
  }

}
```

Above code to add files individually is taken from the sharpcompress [documentation](http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Composite%20API%20Examples&referringTitle=Documentation), with a few extra lines to filter out dll files.